# GeckoDriver not synchronizing with Selenium with Java 11

Tags: selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver, java-11

not able to run the basic selenium code
Using:

- FireFox 52 esr
- Selenium jar 3.141.59
- geckodriver-v0.23.0-win64

Code trials (test.java):

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class test {

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        System.out.println("Hello");
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C://Users//anila//Downloads//geckodriver-v0.23.0-win64//geckodriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("www.google.com");
    }

}
```

> "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.1\bin\java.exe" "-javaagent:C:\Program
>   Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition
>   2018.3.2\lib\idea_rt.jar=59660:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2018.3.2\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath
>   "C:\Users\anila\out\production\anila;C:\Users\anila\Desktop\Selenium
>   Jar\client-combined-3.141.59.jar;C:\Users\anila\Desktop\Selenium
>   Jar\libs\okio-1.14.0.jar;C:\Users\anila\Desktop\Selenium
>   Jar\libs\okhttp-3.11.0.jar;C:\Users\anila\Desktop\Selenium
>   Jar\libs\guava-25.0-jre.jar;C:\Users\anila\Desktop\Selenium
>   Jar\libs\commons-exec-1.3.jar;C:\Users\anila\Desktop\Selenium
>   Jar\libs\byte-buddy-1.8.15.jar;C:\Users\anila\lib\com.springsource.org.testng-6.5.2.jar"
>   test Hello 1547227022145  mozrunner::runner   INFO    Running command:
>   "C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" "-marionette"
>   "-foreground" "-no-remote" "-profile"
>   "C:\Users\anila\AppData\Local\Temp\rust_mozprofile.NnD9S4e3gbOY"
>   [GFX1]: Potential driver version mismatch ignored due to missing DLLs
>   0.0.0.0 and 0.0.0.0 1547227023423 Marionette  INFO    Listening on port 2828 [GFX1]: Potential driver version mismatch ignored due to missing
>   DLLs 0.0.0.0 and 0.0.0.0 [Child 5320] ###!!! ABORT: Aborting on
>   channel error.: file
>   c:/builds/moz2_slave/m-esr52-w64-000000000000000000/build/src/ipc/glue/MessageChannel.cpp,
>   line 2143 Exception in thread "main"
>   org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: connection refused Build info:
>   version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time:
>   '2018-11-14T08:25:48' System info: host: 'LAPTOP-1QFLADIK', ip:
>   '192.168.2.29', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version:
>   '10.0', java.version: '11.0.1' Driver info: driver.version:
>   FirefoxDriver remote stacktrace:      at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native
>   Method)   at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at
>   java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.W3CHandshakeResponse.lambda$errorHandler$0(W3CHandshakeResponse.java:62)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.HandshakeResponse.lambda$getResponseFunction$0(HandshakeResponse.java:30)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.lambda$createSession$0(ProtocolHandshake.java:126)
>     at
>   java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
>     at
>   java.base/java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.tryAdvance(Spliterators.java:958)
>     at
>   java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(ReferencePipeline.java:127)
>     at
>   java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:502)
>     at
>   java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:488)
>     at
>   java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
>     at
>   java.base/java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(FindOps.java:150)
>     at
>   java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
>     at
>   java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(ReferencePipeline.java:543)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:128)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:74)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:136)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:213)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:147)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:125)
>     at test.main(test.java:11)

Answer (score 0):

As per your question and the error trace logs:

- You are using **java.version: '11.0.1'**

As per [Can't compile Java9 module with selenium-java as dependency](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/5896) it seems the *Selenium* packages can't be compiled with **Java 9** due to **split packages** and till *May 15, 2018* Selenium wasn't fully compatible with Java 9.

But as per this [comment](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/pull/6100#issuecomment-402977443) @Jarob22 mentioned, Selenium works just fine using **Java 10**. **Java 9** is already eol and there's not much point adding extra stuff to try and support just it if 10 works.

But with the landing of [e57914a](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/commit/e57914ab0550e7b755bfd664d61040ae7856b03d) Simon introduced us with **basic JPMS support**. With this availability [(mhomnag/selenium-java10-reproducer@bc63889)](https://github.com/mhomnag/selenium-java10-reproducer/commit/bc638891395ca28ef5ae4fc5ecb330991c95a79b) now actually builds but you may have to [Remove the WebDriverWaiter and just use a sleep for now](https://github.com/mhomnag/selenium-java10-reproducer/commit/72f3be2642f2aac82dc3c8ac9398b0d99f07858e).

### Java 11

**selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar** is still not compatible with **Java 11**. But once **Java 11** ships and **Buck** supports it
the toolchain witll be rejiged to support *Java 11*.

Comment: FYI, Same kind of issue with Cucumber: not compatible with Java 11.

Comment: @Max Yes, we need to wait.

Answer (score 0):

The reason your code doesn't work may be that geckodriver 0.23 supports Firefox since **57** version. Check [supported platforms](https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/testing/geckodriver/geckodriver/Support.html) page for more info. Updating Firefox seems to be the best solution. (if you can do it)